# Custom UIView inside TableView Custom Cell "jumps" on table load

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, cell, custom-element

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells inside it called `NewsCell`.
Inside the `NewsCell` I have a custom `UIView` that is used as an action button.

Many times when the `TableView` is loading a cell, the custom action button appears at the **top** of the cell for a few seconds until it goes back down to its right spot at the bottom of the cell. Sometimes it returns to its right place only after I scroll the cell out of the viewport.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is a photo to make things clearer:
[action button out of place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5YmJ.png)

NewsCell was created using .xib file and here is the relevant codes:

```
protocol NewsCellDelegate {
    func favoriteIconDidPress(forArticle article: Article)
    func actionButtonDidPress(inside article: Article)
}

enum ArticleFavoriteMark {
    case selected
    case notSelected
}

class NewsCell: UITableViewCell, MainActionButtonDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var entireNewsCell: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteIcon: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subjectTag: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreSubjectsTag: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: MainActionButtonView!
    
    var delegate: NewsCellDelegate?
    var articleUrl = ""
    var articleID = ""
    var articleImageUrl = ""
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setCellBorder()
        setCellColorsDesign()
        setImageRounded()
        setTagsRounded()
        setGestureRecognizer()
        
        actionButton.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }
     

    func setGestureRecognizer() {
        favoriteIcon.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: favoriteIcon, action: #selector(favoriteIconPressed)))
        favoriteIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(favoriteIconPressed(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        favoriteIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)
    }
    
    
    @objc func favoriteIconPressed(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentArticle = Article(id: articleID, articleTitle: titleLabel.text!, date: dateLabel.text ?? "", url: articleUrl, content: summaryLabel.text!, author: authorLabel.text ?? "", topic: subjectTag.currentTitle!, imageUrl: articleImageUrl , isFavorite: isFavorite)
        delegate?.favoriteIconDidPress(forArticle: currentArticle)
    }
    
    
    func actionButtonDidPress(btnText: String) {
        let currentArticle = Article(
            id: articleID,
            articleTitle: titleLabel.text ?? "",
            date: dateLabel.text ?? "",
            url: articleUrl,
            content: summaryLabel.text ?? "",
            author: authorLabel.text ?? "",
            topic: subjectTag.currentTitle ?? "",
            imageUrl: articleImageUrl,
            isFavorite: self.isFavorite)

        delegate?.actionButtonDidPress(inside: currentArticle)
    }
}
```

This is my `NewsCell` elements hierarchy:

[news cell elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qii2c.png)

And these are the constraints I put on the action button inside the `NewsCell`:

[constraints on action button inside NewsCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLRR.png)

And this is how I constrained the `ActionButton` `UIView`:
[constraints inside the action button custom uiview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8utI.png)

In my TableView I initiate each cell like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.TableCellsIdentifier.FAVORITES, for: indexPath) as! SavedArticleCell
        currentCell.delegate = self
        
        let currentKey = viewModel.keysArray[indexPath.row]
        let savedArticle = viewModel.savedArticles[currentKey]
        
        if let savedArticle = savedArticle {
            currentCell.articleID = savedArticle.id!
            currentCell.articleTitle.text = savedArticle.title
            currentCell.articleTopic.setTitle(savedArticle.topic, for: .normal)
            
            if let imageUrl = savedArticle.imageUrl {
                currentCell.articleImageURL = imageUrl
                currentCell.articleImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "light-gray-background"))
            } else {
                currentCell.articleImage.image = UIImage(named: "light-gray-background")
            }
        }
        
        return currentCell
    }
```

Comment: How did you create the cell (code or interface builder)? Do you set AutoLayout constraints properly? Please, share the code of the cell.

Comment: please provide full code where you configure the cell layout

Comment: @Noam Kurtzer it seems the problem lies with AutoLayout in xib file. Nothing found fishy in ```NewCell``` code.

Comment: Added code of both `NewsCell` and the relevant function in my `TableView` @talha_kuet

Comment: **Align Center Y to: StackView** remove this constraint and check if it works or not. @NoamKurtzer

Comment: @talha_kuet added some screenshots. When I remove the ActionButton from the Custom Class in the NewsCell identity inspector then suddenly the UIView behaves as should

Comment: Also remove **Align Center X to: StackView** as it is redundant. You have already set leading and trailing constraints of the button.

Comment: @talha_kuet Yes the whole StackView was irrelevant, my apologies. Removed it completely and updated the image in my question. Didn't solve the issue though

Comment: Add ```self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()``` and ```self.layoutIfNeeded``` in ```layoutSubViews()``` method before the closing bracket. @NoamKurtzer

Comment: Seems like it solved it!
Why was it needed if I already defined "hard" constraints in the NewsCell? @talha_kuet

Comment: @NoamKurtzer I have added an answer please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `layoutSubViews()` method of `NewsCell`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The purpose of `layoutIfNeeded()` is to force a synchronous (essentially "immediate") redraw of a view and its subviews. You have to call this because you have updated the layout in `layoutsubviews()` method. Regarding `layoutIfNeeded()` Here is what [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) says.

> Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately. When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints. Using the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root. If no layout updates are pending, this method exits without modifying the layout or calling any layout-related callbacks.